# How to use that the Hessian is negative definite to solve this problem

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, proof-explanation, lie-groups

Let $X$ be a  Riemannian compact manifold on which acts a compact Lie group $H^+$. Let $f^+ : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a smooth function on $X$. Consider a Lie subgroup $U$ of $H^+$ and suppose that $U$ acts on the set of critical points of $f^+$.  Denote by $\phi $  the flow of the gradient vector field of $f^+$. Suppose that $\phi$ is $U$-invariant, and that $lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty} \phi_t(x)$ exists and it  belongs to the set of critical points of $f^+$ for all $x \in X$.

Let $\alpha:= U.x_0$ be a $U$-orbit which pass through a critical point $x_0$ and denote by $\alpha^+:= H^+.x_0$ the corresponding $H^+$-orbit on $X$.  Let $C$ be a connected component of $\alpha$ and let $M_C$ be the set $M_C:= \lbrace x \in X, lim_{t \rightarrow+ \infty} \phi_t(x) \in C \rbrace $

$\textbf{Question}$: Show that if  flow  $\phi$ preserves the orbit $\alpha ^+$ and if the Hessian $Hess_x(f^+)$  is negative definite on $T_x( \alpha^+)$ for all $x \in \alpha $,  then  $\alpha^+ \subset M_C $  in a neighborhood $V$ of $C$.

My motivaion to ask this question is to understand the proof of proposition 3.9 in the paper Matsuki correspondence for sheaves.

[image]